# Preserve results of sbt incremental compilation when moving project directory

Tags: scala, sbt, incremental-compiler, zinc

Consider the scenario: I have a simple scala project managed by sbt, in a directory called `foo`.

```
cd foo
sbt compile
```

It now takes a few seconds and the project compiles correctly.

Now, thanks to sbt incremental compilation, if I run

```
sbt compile
```

it terminates the compile task in close to 0 seconds, since the source code hasn't changed.

But if I rename the `foo` directory into `bar`

```
cd ..
mv foo bar
```

and try to compile it again

```
cd bar
sbt compile
```

now the compile task takes again few seconds, hence not using the results from the previous compilation.

Is there a way to preserve the incremental compilation results of a project even when its absolute path on disk has changed?

Comment: ok, apparently sbt stores the results of incremental compilation using an absolute path, and that's why it breaks. Now, how to fix it?

Comment: I would use the sbt gitter channel :) this sound like a pretty involved question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to use Hoarder Plugin: https://github.com/romanowski/hoarder.

Ping me on Hoarder's gitter in case of any questions/problems.

Comment: Thank you! I'm well aware of it, I plan to try it soon! :)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there's some work in progress to make incremental compilation results cacheable. Here's the relevant PR: https://github.com/sbt/zinc/pull/216.

Also, there's an issue (being discussed at the time of this writing) about making zinc's analysis completely machine independent. See https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/218.